# KuCoin get STOP ORDER status

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, kucoin

In order to get the status of the STOP order, I'm using `GET /api/v1/stop-order/{orderId}` as suggested by the [docs](https://docs.kucoin.com/#get-single-order-info), and it has a `status` field in response which could be *new* or *triggered*, but I'm confused about it. *new* meaning is obvious and also *triggered*, but how can I know it's triggered fully?

Does triggered mean that it's sold or bought (based on the side) fully? or it can be triggered partially as well?

Imagine as for my take profit order, I'm creating a *stop market order* after my main buy spot order, so on a for example 5% higher price I want my take profit order (which is a stop market order) to be triggered. Imagine the price goes up 5%, it triggeres my stop market order, but now it needs to be fully filled to be considered a *done order*, how can i know that? based on the status from the response, it only has *new* and *triggered*, and it doesn't define if it's fully filled or not.

This was just an example, stop market order probabely gets filled immediately, the main problem is with my stop loss order, which is a STOP LIMIT type, so it might not get filled on my desired price and I can't know if its triggered fully or not.

Another thing is, if the stop order is stop market type, how may I know the average price it's filled? sice it's a STOP MARKET, then on the trigger price ABOVE/BELOW, it will get filled, how may I know the average price of filled price?

Another thing is, if the stop order is stop market type, how may I know the average price it's filled? sice it's a STOP MARKET, then on the trigger price ABOVE/BELOW, it will get filled, how may I know the average price of filled price?